# how to create a sparse matrix from lists of numbers

Tags: python, list, sparse-matrix

I have three lists namely A , B , C
All these lists contain 97510 items . I need to create a sparse matrix like this

```
matrix[A[0]][B[0]] = C[0]
```

For example ,

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5] 
B=[7,8,9,10,11] 
C=[14,15,16,17,18]
```

I need to create a sparse matrix with

```
matrix[1][7] = 14 # (which is C[0])
matrix[2][8] = 15 # and so on .....
```

I tried and python gives me an error saying that "Index values must be continuous"

How do I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at the [SciPy sparse matrices](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html). E.g. a COO sparse matrix:

```
matrix = sparse.coo_matrix((C,(A,B)),shape=(5,5))
```

Note: I just took the COO matrix because it was in the example, [you can take any other](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html#sparse-matrix-classes). You probably have to try which one is most suitable for your situation. They all differ in the way how the data is compressed and this has an influence on the performance of certain operations.

Comment: This fails for me. ValueError: row index exceeds matrix dimensions

Comment: The dimension isn't set correctly. The right solution should be: sparseMatrix = sparse.coo_matrix((C,(A,B)),shape=(np.max(A)+1,np.max(B)+1))

Answer (score 4):

If you simply need a way how to get matrix[A[0]][B[0]] = C[0] you can use the following:

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5]
B=[7,8,9,10,11]
C=[14,15,16,17,18]

matrix = dict((v,{B[i]:C[i]}) for i, v in enumerate(A))
```

EDITED(thanx for gnibbler):

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
B = [7,8,9,10,11]
C = [14,15,16,17,18]

matrix = dict(((v, B[i]), C[i]) for i, v in enumerate(A))
```

Comment: This won't work properly if there are any duplicate keys in A

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple to use a dict, especially if you are willing to change the way you write the indices slightly

```
>>> A=[1,2,3,4,5] 
>>> B=[7,8,9,10,11] 
>>> C=[14,15,16,17,18]
>>> matrix=dict(((a,b),c) for a,b,c in zip(A,B,C))
>>> matrix[1,7]
14
>>> matrix[2,8]
15
>>>
```

Comment: @Artsiom, for 97k items it is probably better (faster) to use itertools.izip, but I didn't think it warranted the extra complication. (zip in Python3 already returns an iterator anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at numpy/scipy which has support for sparse matrixes. See e.g. [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html)